# Destroying objects on demand with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

What is the correct way to destroy an object with ARC?

I would like to destroy a number of `UIViewController`s as well as an object holding an AUGraph at certain times during runtime.

At the moment, when my parent viewcontroller creates viewcontroller objects and assigns their views to its `view`, the objects obviously stay alive with the parent. I would like to destroy these child viewcontrollers the moment they are not needed.

Comment: In ARC, objects are automatically deallocated when there are no references remaining to them. There should not be any need to destroy them manually. Are you having problems with objects persisting longer than they should?

Comment: Thanks. Not experiencing any problems, but I have a number of child viewcontrollers in a mainviewcontroller and addSubview their views. I want to free up memory when these subviews are not displaying, and just create a destroy them as needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set the variables referencing those objects to `nil`. The compiler will then release the objects at that moment and they will be destroyed if no other strong references to them exist.

Comment: Great thanks. Is there such a concept of "hibernating" viewcontrollers instead of destroying and recreating them?

Comment: What do you mean by "hibernating"? Just keep the reference and the view controller will stay around. As long as its view is not on screen, it will manage its view itself and unload it from memory as soon as your app receives a memory warning (which is the right situation for you to also free unneeded memory such as caches, etc.). If I were you, I wouldn't interfere with this process.

Answer (score 3):

ARC will insert a call to `[release]` when you set a `__strong` variable that references an object to `nil`.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UIViewController *childViewController;
}
...

@end

-(void)destroyChild {
    childViewController = nil;
}
```

The same thing is done when you have a C-style array of objects: setting an element of your array to `nil` releases the item that was there unless it was `__weak`/`__unsafe_unretained`. If you keep child view controllers in an `NSMutableArray`, removing an object from the array decrements its reference count.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can achieve this by setting the object to nil. What's happening behind the scenes is that the object is being released by ARC and then set to nil. This should accomplish what you want.